# Combine multiple FMUs into one

Tags: simulation, modelica, fmi, pyfmi

I have a pandapower network and at some buses I have included batteries and photovoltaics as FMUs. Right now I have a master algorithm that creates the connections between the inputs and the outputs of the different FMUs and it runs the simulation.

My question is if it is possible to combine everything into one FMU, which will combine all the different inputs and all the different outputs together.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Several free and commercial tools provide the capabality to create an FMU from multiple connected FMUS,sometimes called Matryoshka FMUs.

e.g.,

- fmpy with "create fmu_container", see https://github.com/CATIA-Systems/FMPy/blob/master/tests/test_fmu_container.py for an example
- Dymola: import FMUs and re-export as FMU